# concept conjunction syntax in description logic

Tags: logic

I have a simple syntax question. 
I'm trying to make sure I understand the syntax in description logic (describe here https://www.obitko.com/tutorials/ontologies-semantic-web/syntax-and-semantics.html among many other places).

For a moment I curious about the disjunction syntax. While I believe I understand the semantics of the following statement, I'm trying to understand why the use a square cup on the left and a round cup on the right side

$(C \sqcup D)^\mathcal I = C^\mathcal I \cup D^\mathcal I$

Basically this says the disjunction of all individuals that belong to concept C and all individuals that belong to concept D in knowledge base interpretation $\mathcal I$ is equal to the the disjunction of all individuals in C in knowledge base interpretation $\mathcal I$ and all individuals in D in knowledge base interpretation $\mathcal I$. (Please correct this if wrong)

That seem simply enough, but why the change in the disjunction symbol. It seems like the same operator in both cases.

Comment: It is only a notational issue; [square cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic#Syntax) is *union* of concepts. With an interpretation $\mathcal I$ with domain $\Delta$, a concept $C$ is mapped to a subset $C^{\mathcal I}$ of $\Delta$. Thus, the operations on intepretations of concepts are usual operations with sets.

Comment: The same happens in standard predicate logic where we interpret $Px \lor Qx$ as $P^{\mathcal I} \cup Q^{\mathcal I}$.

Comment: so analogous to the statement from predicate logic is it fair to say that: the left hand side expresses the conjunctions of the individuals that belong to class C and the individuals of class D while the right side expresses the conjunction of concept C and concept D (?)

Comment: awesome, thanks. That's very helpful. And sorry about the confusion of disjunction/conjunction. I fixed it in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only a notational issue; [square cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic#Syntax) is union (or disjunction) of *concepts*.

With an interpretation $\mathcal I$ with domain $\Delta$, a concept $C$ is mapped to a subset $C^{\mathcal I}$ of $\Delta$. Thus, the operations on intepretations of concepts are usual operations with sets.

In the formula above, the LHS is the interpretation of the union of two concepts while the RHS is the union of the interpetations.

The "square cup" is an operation on concepts while the "round cup" is an operation on sets that are the interpretation of concepts.

Comment: What do you think about trying to capture what you've said as follows?
LHS: everything that is a Dog OR everything that is a Cat (in the ${\mathcal I}$ of $\Delta$) (which could also be {d1, d2... dn} or {c1,c2...cn}$^{\mathcal I}$)
RHS: Dogs$^{\mathcal I}$ OR Cats$^{\mathcal I}$
(That's kind of how I read the analogous statement in predicate logic)

Comment: @Jeff - It is difficult, because the "equation" is between sets that are extensions of *concepts*. The two sets are equal, that means that "a thing is "either a cat or a dog" **iff** either is "a cat" or is "a dog" ".

Comment: ok, its getting clear. i really appreciate your help. I'll keep reading!

Comment: @Jeff - you are welcome :-)